# Как пишется: "учащиХся" или "учащиМся" в следующей фразе?

Tags: орфография

Фраза такая:

*с целью оказания профориентационной поддержки учащи?ся в процессе выбора ими профиля обучения и сферы будущей профессиональной*

Заранее благодарю.
Дмитрий.

Answer (score 1):

УчащиМся.

"Оказания профориентационной поддержки (кому?) учащимся". Это дательный падеж, поэтому пишется через "м".

Comment: Ага, значит если бы не было слова ОКАЗАНИЯ,  то было бы УчащиХся?

Comment: @ДмитрийКазаченко верно, поскольку тогда у нас получилось бы "_с целью профориентационной поддержки (кого?) учащиХся_".

Comment: Спасибо)...............